# Combining functions with boundaries in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function like this:

```
f(x) = {  x     if 0 < x < n
       {  n-x   if n < x < 2*n
```

How to enter this function in MATLAB?

Comment: And when `x < 0`? And for `x > 2·n`?

Comment: In this example x should be 0, thank you for remembering me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way is to put this in a sub-function or nested function, or in a separate m-file:

```
function y = f(x)
    n = 4; %// Or whatever your N is

    if x <= 0 || x >= 2*n
        y = 0;     
    elseif x < n
        y = x;
    else
        y = n-x; 
    end
end
```

or, more generally, when `x` is a vector/matrix,

```
function y = f(x)
    y = x;        
    y(x >= n) = n-x(x >= n);
    y(x <= 0 | x >= 2*n) = 0;
end
```

Alternatively, you can of course pass the `n` as an argument:

```
function y = f(x, n)
    ...
end
```

Alternatively, you can use this anonymous function:

```
 f = @(x) (x>0 & x<n).*x + (x>=n & x<=2*n).*(n-x);
```

again, optionally, pass the `n`:

```
 f = @(x,n) ...
```

Comment: I think this will do. Thank you!

Comment: @arc_lupus: Note that this includes `n`, so `y=n-x` when `x >= n` (you did't mention what happens at `x=n`, I assumed the logical thing :)

Comment: Based on the comment `NaN` should become 0.

Comment: I'd go with the anonymous option. +1